# Stack code in C crashes and stops working as soon as it is run

Tags: c, pointers, stack

So, I was working on a standard stack program in C with push, pop etc. The code compiles fine but as soon as I run it, it crashes and a 'stopped working' message is shown. I am working on a Dev C++ application on a windows system. The code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

struct stack {
    int items[MAX];
    int top;
};
typedef struct stack st;

void createemptyStack(st *s) {
    s->top = -1;
}

int isEmpty(st *s) {
    if (s->top == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isFull(st *s) {
    if (s->top == MAX - 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int push(st *s) {
    int newitem;

    printf("Enter the value you want to push");
    scanf("%d", &newitem);

    if (isFull(s)) {
        printf("Stack is full");
    } else {
        s->top++;
        s->items[s->top] = newitem;
    }
}

void pop(st *s) {
    if (isEmpty(s)) {
        printf("Stack is empty");
    } else {
        printf("Items popped %d", s->items[s->top]);
        s->top--;   
    }
}

int main() {
    int ch;
    int loop = 1;
    st *s;

    createemptyStack(s);

    do {
        printf("\n ***STACK OPERATIONS");
        printf("\n 1. PUSH");
        printf("\n 2. POP");
        printf("\n 3. EXIT");
        printf("\n ***************");
        printf("\n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch (ch) {
          case 1:
            push(s);
            break;

          case 2:
            pop(s);
            break;

          case 3:
            printf("Visit again");      
            loop = 0;
            exit(0);

          default:
            printf("Invalid choice");
        }   
    } while(loop);

    getch();
}
```

Would really be helpful for me if you can help me in this matter. I think the problem might reside in the `do / while` loop but I am not sure. Would like some opinions on this matter.

Comment: `s` is never allocated.

Comment: general thought. Separate the logic for push and pop from the prompting of the user etc. Imagine at some other time you might want to push values read from a file, or generated by an algorithm....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  st *s;
```

you are not allocating memory to `*s`,
 change it to

```
  st *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

or

```
  st s;
  createemptyStack(&s)
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `s` which is a pointer to `st` is uninitialized and hence contains garbage data. Now when you pass `s` to `createemptyStack` it tries to access memory location pointed by garbage data in `s` leading to segmentation fault.
You first need to allocate space for structure by either defining a struct object

```
st obj;
st* s = &obj;
```

or by dynamic memory allocation

```
s = malloc(sizeof(st))
```

Answer (score 1):

`s` is defined as a pointer to a stack object. You need an actual `struct stack` object for `s` to point to. Either define one as a local variable:

```
st obj;
st *s = &obj;
```

or allocate one from the heap:

```
st *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
if (s == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure\n");
    exit(1);
}
```